# How can I iterate over objects and arrays of objects in an object and run the same function in each object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure:

```
const test1 = {
  hero: {
    update() {
      console.log('updated hero in object');
    },
  },
  zombies: [
    {
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 1 in array of objects');
      },
    },
    {
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 2 in array of objects');
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I can manually run the functions with:

```
test1.hero.update()
test1.zombies[0].update()
test1.zombies[1].update()
```

But there will be hundreds of zombies, and other arrays and single objects.

Do I need recursion to run them all, or maybe `filter` or `reduce` could be used? I have the following code snippet, but I can't seem to make it run the functions. The fact the KEY is update and the VALUE is update() is throwing me somehow!

I did cheat before and just put the `hero` in an array by itself and then it is easy using `Object.keys` and 2x nested `forEach`s, but it seems a weak solution

```
// Code shows keys and values of everything, but can't run update()
const iterate = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`KEY: ${key}, VALUE: ${obj[key]}`);
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      iterate(obj[key]);
    }
  });
};

iterate(test1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to achieve this. Here is an example:

```js
const test1 = {
  hero: {
    update() {
      console.log('updated hero in object');
    },
  },
  zombies: [
    {
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 1 in array of objects');
      },
    },
    {
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 2 in array of objects');
      },
    },
  ],
};

Array.prototype.flatMap = function (lambda) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda));
};

const caller = (data) => {
  Object.entries(data)
    .flatMap((keyValueArray) => {
      const [key, objOrArrayValue] = keyValueArray;
      if (objOrArrayValue instanceof Array) {
        return objOrArrayValue;
      }
      return [objOrArrayValue];
    })
    .forEach(obj => obj.update());
};

caller(test1);
```

PS: for demostration, I obtained the `flatMap` implementation from [here](https://gist.github.com/samgiles/762ee337dff48623e729)

Comment: Thanks! This was a bit faster than the nice recursion version from @DacreDenny. The only thing that seems hard to read is the `{ 1: objOrArray }` part having the `1`, if this could somehow be refactored it would be perfection :) Also flatMap() is supported almost everywhere now, so that is great.

Comment: Just to give an explanation to the previous syntax. Given that the first parameter of a function is an Array, then this syntax `{1: objOrArray}` gets the second item in that array. Hope this makes sense. @Sumomo

Comment: Cheers! I am going to stare at that for a long time until I fully understand :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved via the `updateEntityArray()` function (see below) which provides a generic, recursive solution:

```js
const test1 = {
  hero: {
    update() {
      console.log('updated hero in object');
    },
  },
  zombies: [
    {
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 1 in array of objects');
      },
    },
    { 
      update() {
        console.log('updated zombie 2 in array of objects');
      },
    },
  ],
};

/* Generic function that recursively calls update() on items
in supplied entities */
const updateEntities = (entities) => {

  /* Iterate values of supplied entities */
  for(const entity of Object.values(entities)) {
  
    /* If this entity has an update function defined then call it */
    if(typeof entity.update === 'function') {
      entity.update();
    }
    
    /* If this entity is iterable then recursively call updateEntities
    where any updatable children of this entity will be up updated as
    well */
    if(typeof entity[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
      updateEntities(entity);
    }
  } 
}

updateEntities(test1);
```